# Изменение фрагментов в контейнере

Tags: android, android-fragment

На главном экране в MainActivity есть контейнер LinearLayout и в него нужно в зависимости от условия подгружать нужный фрагмент.
Если контейнер пустой, то нужно подгружать дефолтный фрагмент с сообщением, на подобии "еще нет созданных объектов". А когда создаются эти объекты, ну то бишь другие фрагменты, то нужно тот дефолтный убрать и поместить новый. Как это реализовать?

Comment: Добавьте немного кода, для лучшего понимания ситуации

Comment: возможно через проверку if на существование объекта (фрагмента)

Comment: 1. Проверяем наличие объектов. Если есть - грузим. Всё. Если нет - делаем слушателя создания объектов. Потом занимаемся объектами. Когда они готовы - уведомляем слушателя и грузим объекты. Убиваем слушателя.

Comment: Красавчик! Я таки сам допер как реализовать, и совсем забыл, что оставлял вопрос. Но, в любом случае, спасибо